# Expressing $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin 2x}{x+1}\,dx$ using $A = \int_0^\pi\frac{\cos x}{(x+2)^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $$A = \int_0^\pi\frac{\cos x}{(x+2)^2}\,dx,$$ 
then find the value of $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin 2x}{x+1}\,dx$$ in terms of $A$.

Comment: **Hint**: Try an integration by parts for the first integral and try $u = 2x$ in your second integral

Comment: Yeah! That works! Thank you so much. :))

Comment: @NoFluxGiven If using the hint in the previous comment you were able to find solution, one possibility what to do would be to post it as an answer yourself. (Especially if you consider that the question might be useful for other users too. And, as a bonus, people will look at your solution and check whether it's ok.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the substitution $x \mapsto 2x $ gives

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin 2x}{2x+2}2dx = \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x+2}dx $$

Integration by parts gives

$$ \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x+2}dx = -\frac{\cos x}{x+2}\Bigg\vert_0^\pi - \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos x}{(x+2)^2}dx = \frac{1}{\pi+2} + \frac12 - A $$